# Python 3 Tkinter OptionsMenu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been searching around and i am not able to find a proper explanation of the syntax of OptionMenu within Tkinter.

how would i get the current chosen option with in the OptionMenu?

```
    def homeTeamOption(self, frame, sortedList):

    def func():
        print(homeTeamName)
        return 

    homeTeam = tk.StringVar(frame)
    returnValueAwayTeam = []

    options = sortedList
    homeTeamName = tk.StringVar()
    drop = OptionMenu(frame, homeTeamName, *options, command=func())
    drop.place(x=200, y= 100, anchor="nw")
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the `OptionMenu` you need to get the value of the associated variable. In your case it would be:

```
homeTeamName.get()
```

If you want to do this via the `command`, you must set the option to a reference to the function:

```
drop = OptionMenu(...command=func)
```